# How to resize images before uploading with Active Storage (linked with AWS)

Tags: amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, minimagick

I try to use Active Storage with Amazon Web Services, instead of Carrierwave and Cloudinary.

With Carrierwave I had some features that allow to resize images before uploading trough an UploaderController.

But how to do that with Active Storage ?

I try this :

Gemfile :

```
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
gem 'mini_magick', '~>4.9'
```

item.rb

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :photo
end
```

I have a form in my view :

```
<%= f.input :photo, input_html: { accept: ('image') } %>
```

I get this object as photo :

```
#<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00005641d296e1b8 @name="photo", @record=#<Item id: nil, name: "test0941", verbe: "To Lend", collection_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, price_cents: 0, description: "", category_id: 78, photo: nil>, @dependent=:purge_later>
```

And in my controller :

```
@item = Item.new(item_params)
@item.photo.combine_options do |b|
    b.resize "250x200>"
end
```

I can't achieve to resize my photo with methods of MiniMagick gem.

Does anybody have any ideas to do that ?

Thanks for your help,
Thibault

Answer (score 10):

If params[:item][:photo] is the param from your post you can add

```rb
image = MiniMagick::Image.new(params[:item][:photo].tempfile.path)
image.resize "250x200>"
```

With ImageProcessing::Vips (default in Rails 7)

```rb
path = params[:game][:photo].tempfile.path
image = ImageProcessing::Vips.source(path)
result = image.resize_to_limit!(800, 800)
params[:game][:photo].tempfile = result
```

Comment: This works, but in my case I had to remove :photo from item_params, apply the logic above, then attach the photo with @item.photo.attach(params[:item][:photo]).

Comment: I needed contextual information to make it work. Those two lines must be in the controller, in create and/or update action. First define your object as usual, like `@obj = Obj.new(params[:id])`, if it's a create action. Then add the two lines in this answer. If your model has `has_many_attached`, you have to iterate through `params[:object][:attachment]`, or whatever you have. Finally just save the object!

Answer (score 3):

Add this as a `private` method to your controller:

```rb
def resize_before_save(image_param, width, height)
  return unless image_param

  begin
    ImageProcessing::MiniMagick
      .source(image_param)
      .resize_to_fit(width, height)
      .call(destination: image_param.tempfile.path)
  rescue StandardError => _e
    # Do nothing. If this is catching, it probably means the
    # file type is incorrect, which can be caught later by
    # model validations.
  end
end
```

Then call it from a `before_action` in the controller.

```rb
before_action lambda {
  resize_before_save(item_params[:picture], 250, 250)
}, only: [:create, :update]
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

```
# config/initializers/activestorage.rb

# Ability to auto apply :default variant (if defined) before uploading original image
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  ActiveStorage::Blob.class_eval do
    alias_method :upload_without_unfurling_orig, :upload_without_unfurling
    
    def upload_without_unfurling(io)
      variant = attachments.first.send(:variants)
      default_variant = variant[:default]
      if default_variant
        ActiveStorage::Variation.wrap(default_variant).transform(io) do |output|
          unfurl output, identify: identify
          upload_without_unfurling_orig(output)
        end
      else
        upload_without_unfurling_orig(io)
      end
    end
  end
end

# user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :photo do |attachable|
    attachable.variant :thumb, resize_to_fill: [100, nil]
    # This variant will be applied before uploading the original image
    attachable.variant :default, strip: true, quality: 70, resize_to_fill: [500, 500]
  end
end

# rspec
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  describe 'when uploading photo' do
    it 'applies :default variant before uploading the original image' do
      allow(ActiveStorage::Variation).to receive(:wrap).and_call_original
      create(:user, :with_photo)
      exp_args = hash_including(resize_to_fill: [500, 500])
      expect(ActiveStorage::Variation).to have_received(:wrap).with(exp_args)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -4):

Active storage has a solution for your problem.
You don't need to resize images in your controller.You can just use it as 
item.photo.variant(resize: '100x100') in your view file. Active Storage will create new variant images like magic.

## Here is the documentation for active storage.

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html

Comment: This is a good solution to small websites but, when your website starts to grow up it could become a bad idea. A better approach could be resized in many versions before save and then uses the appropriated in each case.